# VS 2010 C++ Express support of BitBlt()

Tags: c++, graphics, visual-studio-2010

I want to reduce screen flicker by drawing a small image to a compatible device context, then using bltbit() to copy this small image to window hdc.  Can I do this using VS C++ 2010 express?   Function bltbit() appears not to work.

Comment: Should work fine... VS Express doesn't restrict anything with regard to what APIs/functions you can use. You should post the error and the code that's causing it.

Comment: You included <Windows.h>?

Comment: I thought I had replied to this some time ago, but my comment isn't present.  At any rate, what I had said before was that, reassured by @dvnrrs that I wasn't beating my head against a wall, I finally figured out the right combination of statements to make my code work properly.  The bug was not with bitblt() but with statements that preceded it.  I now routinely update window content via a memory DC.

Comment: ...it's "BitBlt", not "BltBit".